# Umbraco - Change culture programmatically

Tags: umbraco, multilingual, culture

I'm trying to change Umbraco Culture with French/English button in top-left corner. When I click this button, I redirect to a function :

```
public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(string lang)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);

    var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;

    Response.Redirect(url.ToString());

    return Content("");
}
```

I've debugged and my `lang` parameter is ok, but the `CurrentCulture` is never saved when the page is refreshed.

Comment: When you debug the project, what is CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang) returning?

Comment: How are  the different languages handled in umbraco? If you redirect to the same "url" you will get the same CurrentCulture as before, maybe you should redirect to something like /lang/ + url